# How to add an index to a JSON object from a Variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a list of files that have a JSON array inside:

```
let rawTopTeams = fs.readFileSync('topTeams.json');
let topTeams = JSON.parse(rawTopTeams);
let allResults = [];
topTeams.teams.forEach(function(value){
    teamId = value.id;
    let resultsJson = fs.readFileSync('team '+ teamId +'.json');
    let resultsParsed = JSON.parse(resultsJson); 

// I want to combine them into a unique JSON, and I want to add the file name as a key: 

    allResults[teamId] = resultsParsed;
```

Problem is this doesn't work. Tried doing teamId.toString() but it doesn't change the result (for teamId = 6137):

```
[
  <6137 empty items>,
  [
    {
      INFO HERE
    },
  ]
]
```

How can I combine all of these JSON files, and organize them under their unique ID so I can find them afterwards?

Comment: Edited to add that.

Comment: `[]` is array syntax, which should have numerical indexes.  Is `value.id` a number?  I suspect you are after an object instead.  Which would be like `let allResults = {}; allResults.stuff = resultsJson; allResults[teamId] = resultsParsed;`

Comment: BTW, I'm confused as to why people drop by and downvote my question. I'm making sure I'm offering as much context as possible without making it confusing, and I'm researching the question beforehand to see if I find someone with the exact same issue somewhere. What gives?

Comment: Usages of object notation are considered by many to be some of the basics of javascript.  So asking a question related to that can be viewed as not doing enough research before hand, as there are lots of existing references about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is create an object hash with the keys being the team ids

```
    let rawTopTeams = fs.readFileSync('topTeams.json');
    let topTeams = JSON.parse(rawTopTeams);
    let allResults = {}; // Notice I changed this to object
    topTeams.teams.forEach(function(value){
        teamId = value.id;
        let resultsJson = fs.readFileSync('team '+ teamId +'.json');
        let resultsParsed = JSON.parse(resultsJson); 

        // This will now add resultsParsed as a subobject of key teamId under allResults object
        allResults[teamId] = resultsParsed;
```

Answer (score 0):

.The question is not exactly clear to me  but in case I understood it correctly You might better opt for using `reduce`; could be similar to the following

```
let rawTopTeams = fs.readFileSync('topTeams.json');
let topTeams = JSON.parse(rawTopTeams);
let allResults = topTeams.teams.reduce((acc, team) => {
  let resultsJson = fs.readFileSync('team '+ team.id +'.json');
  acc[team.id] = JSON.parse(resultsJson);
  return acc
}, {});
```

Comment: also....are You sure that the files named as `team WhateverTeamId.json`  are there.... the space is suspect to me